# Recover from Windows Update that killed boot up

Tags: backup, disk-image, system-restore, windows-backup

I recently had a near death experience where my system wouldn't boot after a Windows Update. I was finally able to fix it but it made me realize next time I might not be so lucky. So questions:

1. There used to be (I'm thinking back to Windows XP) a way to create a recovery CD (maybe USB now) that could boot my system. And then from that boot up, copy files if Windows is truly screwed up but in most cases roll back update(s). Does that still exist? Is it worth doing? And if so, what/how?
2. I presently use Carbonite to back up my system. If I lose my computer (problematic windows update, drive crash, theft), while I have all the files, I still need to go reinstall all the apps, etc. so the registry is all correct. Is there a way to back up an image of my drive so that I can, assuming I have the same type computer/hard drive, can then write that image to the new hard drive? (And then do a Carbonite restore to catch any changes since the last disk imaging.)

**Update:**

Here's my question - what should I be doing to backup my system to handle all issues from a problematic Windows update to theft of my computer? I think the answer breaks down to one of two basic approaches:

1. Is it stick with Carbonite and recovery means start with a freshly formatted hard drive, install Windows, download all of Carbonite, then reinstall all my programs.
2. Image the hard drive, create a bootable recovery disk, use one of them to get my existing hard drive back. The use Carbonite to download any files changed since the imaged copy of the disk (if have to use that).

Based on the initial comments, I'm leaning toward option #1. It's a very rare (hopefully never) event and so, if it happens, just rebuild. But if there's a better solution for some of these cases, please let me know.

Comment: Carbonite and similar services do not allow you to backup the file extensions that correlate to those of software that create images of your HDD.  Carbonite only is good for backing up your personal files.  As you have properly identified you need to backup the image of your HDD, in order to, restore the entire HDD.  What software you use to do that is entirely up to you, keeping in mind, you also have to backup those images otherwise they are not helpful if they become corrupt.

Comment: Recovery Disk is useless, that environment, exists on your HDD, and every Windows 10 ISO that exist. WinRE doesn't change from a "Recovery Disk" to "Windows 10" ISO, to the Recovery partition that exists on your drive.

Answer (score 1):

Your method does not protect you from all the corruption that can be caused
by a bad Windows update.

To be absolutely safe, you need to take a total backup of the entire
disk, and to be able to boot from an emergency boot media to restore
the backup, in case Windows won't boot any more.

An example product that I like is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
(but others exist).
It will by default only backup used sectors from the disk,
therefore speeding the backup process and reducing the size of the
backup image.

If using AOMEI, you will also need to
[Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html).

I recommend taking a backup image regularly on at least two backup disks
used in rotation.